# Impact of clustered file systems on programming if any?

Tags: language-agnostic, filesystems, cluster-computing

I have a huge number of files that my cluster nodes must reach (think a bout a bunch of configuration parameters i have to apply to my computations). 
We are considering deploying a SAN with a clustered file system (GFS or OCFS), the thing is I dont't know how my program would be impacted (would I have to deal with file locking ?)

This is maybe completely dumb, but it's a bit like a paradigm shift for me and I need to be sure.

thanks